# Bot with timeout callback resets every 20 min. when deployed on Azure?

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

I have build a bot using the JavaScript SDK4 of MS BotBuilder, and deployed it on Azure. I am using it to send reminders every time interval to a Telegram chat group by using setInterval and callback function that pro-actively writes a message to the group every time interval.

When testing it locally with emulator, it works fine. However, when deployed on Azure, it only works until around 20 min. since the setInterval function has been called. After 20 min., the bot seemingly "resets" and the timeout is gone.

I did not find anything in the BotBuilder docu whether there is a fixed reset period or if the bot is switched off after certain time of inactivity. I am using the free tier of the Azure bot app and web app service.

Does anybody know why the bot "resets" after 20 min.?

Comment: Is your App Service set to be _always on_? If not, set that in _Application Settings_ and give it a try.

Comment: Thanks this solved the issue!